# Frontend to AI system (LLM) plugin for transforming longer text chunks to simple modern language

Tags: web-apps, text-processing, artificial-intelligence, web-apis, llm

How to translate/rephrase a verse epic in unreadable language (with bad typesetting) to modern spoken languages?

I intend to purchase an ebook of the Iliad by Homer.

This is a translation from ancient Greek to German, to quite modern German in fact. however that Language is is not modern enough for me. The typesetting (lowercase-only) is annoying, and generelly  word ordering is difficult:

`Prompt: "Wandle dies in einfache Sprache mit korrekter Klein-und Großschreibung um"`

```
von der bitternis sing, göttin - von achilleús, dem sohn des peleús
seinem verfluchten groll, der den griechen unsägliches leid brachte
und die seelen zahlloser krieger hinab in das haus des hades sandte
die blutvollen leben dann nur noch fleisch an dem die hunde fraßen
den vögeln ein festmahl - und wie zeus’ wille sich dadurch erfüllte ...
sing, muse, und beginn mit dem moment wo der göttliche achilleús
sich in einem streit mit seinem kriegsherrn agamemnon entzweite.
doch welcher der götter hatte sie gegeneinander aufgehetzt?
es war apollon, zeus’ sohn mit leto: vor lauter ärger über agamemnon
hatte er im lager eine pest ausbrechen lassen die das heer dahinraffte;
apollons priester chr  ́yses war nicht gebührend ehre erwiesen worden
als der bei den griechischen schiffen erschien, um für sehr viel gold
seine gefangene tochter freizukaufen.
```

Source: [official reading sample](https://bilder.buecher.de/zusatz/23/23456/23456208_lese_1.pdf), Promotion material of the publisher

ChatGPT 4, via Bing, transforms this into the much more readable

> Singe, Muse, und beginne mit dem Moment, als der göttliche Achilleus sich in einem Streit mit seinem Kriegsherrn Agamemnon entzweite.
> Doch welcher der Götter hatte sie gegeneinander aufgehetzt? Es war Apollon, Zeus’ Sohn mit Leto. Vor lauter Ärger über Agamemnon hatte er im Lager eine Pest ausbrechen lassen, die das Heer dahinraffte. Apollons Priester Chryses war nicht gebührend Ehre erwiesen worden, als er bei den griechischen Schiffen erschien, um für sehr viel Gold seine gefangene Tochter freizukaufen.

I am looking for a plugin to chatGPT or Bard or any other AI system that cann automate this process.

It should transform *whole chapters* into this simple language, not just whole paragraphs. Ideally, whole e-books.

I know how to send chunks of text myself, via a REST API, but I am looking for a more comfortable solution. Can be a web app or a Phone app, small service charge would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

A [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iR99LO28nzM) ("Uploading Files to ChatGPT: A More Powerful Experience", by User "Automate my life") explaining a Chrome Plugin ["ChatGPT File Uploader"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chatgpt-file-uploader/oaogphgfdbdbmhkiplemgehihiiececj) has become available.

A more complex example, ["Book translation"](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/tree/main/examples/book_translation) is available as a  [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/tree/main/examples/book_translation). The Authors of the ["OpenAI Cookbook"](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook) show how to translate a math-book typeset in Latex, containing hundreds of equations, from Serbian to English, using the OpenAI REST API.
This example does not work for me though. The max chunk lengths have been  changed recently. Many sentences are too long for the max chunk length.